# PDO Search query with Multiple tags

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this form in HTML

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="tags">
      <label class="tag" for="TAG1"><input type="checkbox" id="TAG1" value="TAG1" name="tags[]">TAG1</label>
      <label class="tag" for="TAG2"><input type="checkbox" id="TAG2" value="TAG2" name="tags[]">TAG2</label>
      <label class="tag" for="TAG3"><input type="checkbox" id="TAG3" value="TAG3" name="tags[]">TAG3</label>
      <label class="tag" for="TAG4"><input type="checkbox" id="TAG4" value="TAG4" name="tags[]">TAG4</label>
      <label class="tag" for="TAG5"><input type="checkbox" id="TAG5" value="TAG5" name="tags[]">TAG5</label>
  </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Then here is my PHP in brief

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $tag = $_POST['tags']
        $query = "
        SELECT a.title FROM posts a
        INNER JOIN tags b ON a.id = b.pid
        WHERE b.tag IN (:tag)
        ";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(['tag' => $tag]);
    }
```

How can i search for multiple selected tags in my code query exactly? I keep getting

`Notice: Array to string conversion`

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR Worked pretty good, But i got a weird problem wrote it in a comment under your answer, Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql `IN` accepts a string delimited by `comma(,)` and you are passing the array inside that, so you are getting warning message, just implode your tags array to make it a string as

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $tag = implode(",",$_POST['tags']);
    $query = "
    SELECT a.title FROM posts a
    INNER JOIN tags b ON a.id = b.pid
    WHERE b.tag IN (:tag)
    ";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(['tag' => $tag]);
}
```

Comment: It worked, But for example, If i have 1 title in a table with the tags `PHP` and `PDO`, If i select only 1 tag of them, The title appears, But if selected both tags, nothing appears, Is the problem is using `IN`?

Comment: you used join in your  query, if the join query satisfied then you got the result based on where condition